# The remote server returned an error: NotFound. Object graph for type 'type' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled

Tags: c#, .net, linq, wcf, silverlight

So I have a project that runs on WCF services in C# backend and Silverlight on the frontend. It uses Linq to SQL modelling to form the model. Now I have to add one new property to the existing table. Initially, I did it by making new columns in the database and then deleting the existing table in the dbml layout and adding it again so that I can retrieve all the new columns. Whenever I run my application after adding new columns, it always gives me an error saying **The remote server returned an error: NotFound.**

So, I did a bit of research and found out about the WCF tracing to figure out the error. Turns out the tracing was giving me this error: **There was an error while trying to serialize parameter :LoadResult. The InnerException message was 'Object graph for type *type* contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.**

So I researched more and it turns out I had to include **isReference=true** to my DataContract. I did exactly the same but I still don't know why I am getting this error.

```
    [DataContract(IsReference=true)]
    public class LoadData
    {
      [DataMember]
      public ServiceException Error;
```

Been debugging this for over 2 days now!! Help!

Comment: Do you need to return the whole ServiceException?  You could just send Error.Message, or call Error.ToString() so that your DataMember is just a string. Often that is enough for most usages. If not, you’ll probably need to customize the Silverlight deserialization, and that can get really difficult.  Especially with built in types like the exceptions as often the Silverlight versions of these types is different on the client (which is using Silverlight libraries) than on the server (which is using .net framework libraries).

Comment: ServiceException is just one of the classes that is a DataMember. I have several Serializable classes after this :( How can we customize Silverlight deserialization?

Comment: You won’t run into this with most serializable types, only rare ones, like this exception, which includes the type Type, which contains circular refs. The only thing I generally do with an exception is log it and maybe show it to the user, so it’s easy to avoid passing it to the Silverlight client: just turn it into the string I’ll show to the user, and pass that. If you want you could look to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6065081 to try customizing the serialization, but I wouldn’t recommend that approach to solve this.  I would just not have a DataMember of type ServiceException.